# Sync SFTP server with DropBox

Tags: sync, dropbox, sftp

I'm using Windows. I have a folder on a server that I can access via SFTP. I want to keep it in sync with a folder on Dropbox. Is there an easy way to do this?

When a file is moved to Dropbox, I also want to apply encryption so it will be protected at rest. Conversely, when it's fetched from Dropbox, I want it decrypted before it goes to the server.

Comment: It is not relevant that you access your files via SFTP. You just need a Dropbox encryptor on the Windows server.

Comment: The encryption part is important but secondary. The main point is synchronizing. The file server is dedicated, embedded Linux so I can't program it. I need something that will help with the sync.

I'm looking at Pneumatic Tube as part of the solution https://github.com/hartez/PneumaticTube, which lets me transfer files back and forth directly to Dropbox. But I still have to compare the contents on each and synchronize accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that I'm thinking that can solve your problem.

One is by resorting to a third party program which basically does what you want. It will encrypt anything that goes to Dropbox but requires a client to be installed on your system to be able to access your data.
http://www.pcworld.com/article/2046475/five-free-dropbox-tools-youre-not-using-but-should-be-.html

Another way is to write your own scripts to be enable you to do the same thing. The only thing here is that you need to watch for sub-standard encryption implementations, programs, etc... (though in this case I don't think that'll be too big of an issue?)

The final way is to use something like Sikuli or SuperMacro to achieve basically the same thing as scripting will achieve except in a graphical environment (more friendly for non-programmers)
http://www.sikuli.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Couchdrop's SFTP integration](//couchdrop.io/sftp).

All you need to do within a terminal is

```
sftp username@couchdrop.io:/
```

and this will then start an interactive session with Dropbox, Box, GoogleDrive or whatever endpoint you chose to integrate with.